# Saving a many to many column in postgres using typeorm

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have an entity of products which looks like

```
@Entity('products')
export class productsEntity extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

         //..columns

    @ManyToMany( type => Categories, categoryEntity => categoryEntity.products)
    categories: string;
```

}
Then i have an entity called category

```
@Entity('Categories')
export class Categories extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({nullable: false, default: 'all', unique: true})
    title: string;

    @ManyToMany(()=> productsEntity, product => product.categories)
    products: productsEntity[];
}
```

Also i have a DTO to validate.

```
export class addProductDto{
 
     // other DTO'S

    @IsNotEmpty({ message: "category needs to be set."})
    categories: Categories[];

}
```

Now when i try to save a new product in products table everything seems to work fine except categories column.

```
@EntityRepository(productsEntity)
export class productsRepository extends Repository<productsEntity> {
    private connection: Connection
    private logger = new Logger();

    async addProduct(productDetails, username){
        const {title, description, belongsTo, price, units}  = productDetails;
        try{
            let newProduct = new productsEntity();
            newProduct.title = title;
            newProduct.description = description;
            newProduct.categories = belongsTo
            newProduct.price = price;
            newProduct.units = units;
            newProduct.soldBy = username;
            await this.manager.save(newProduct);
        }
        catch(err){
            this.logger.error(err.message);
            throw new HttpException('Failed adding Product.', HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        }
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong here??
All the fields get saved but categories doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

first, you have to @JoinTable at the products entity and also use the cascades option to save both sides with one save command the last thing is the type of categories is Categories[]

```
@Entity('products')
export class productsEntity extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

         //..columns

    @ManyToMany( type => Categories, categoryEntity => categoryEntity.products , {cascade : true ,})
    @JoinTable({name : 'products-catigories'})

    categories: Categories[];
```

finally it will works fine

Comment: I am sorry but it shows no effect and doing the same things saving everything into products except categories.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to import it => use QueryBuilder in your service or repository
just change the $ID with the product id or catigory id

```
import { getRepository } from "typeorm";
 
    public async getProducts(id) {
    let query = getRepository(productsEntity)
    .createQueryBuilder('product')
    .where('product.id = : id' , {id : $ID})
    .leftJoinAndSelect('product.categories' , 'catigories')
    const product = query.getOne()
    return product
}
```

```
import { getRepository } from "typeorm";

public async getCatigories(id) {
    let query = getRepository(Catigories)
    .createQueryBuilder('catigory')
    .where('catigory.id = : id' , {id : $ID})
    .leftJoinAndSelect('catigory.products' , 'products')
    const product = query.getOne()
    return product
```

Comment: sorry but that's not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

you also can use find Options and its an easier way

```
const getOneProduct= await this.entity.findOne(id , {relations : ["categories"]})
const getAllProducts= await this.entity.find({relations : ["categories"]})
```

it will add the categories to the product result